# MSSql - show columns side by side based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with rows similar to this

```
+-----+-------+---------------+
|  id | time  | linked init id|
+-----+-------+---------------+    
|  1  + 10.00 |     0         |
+-----+-------+---------------+    
|  2  + 11.00 |     0         |
+-----+-------+---------------+
|  3  + 15.00 |     1         |
+-----+-------+---------------+ 
|  4  + 10.00 |     0         |
+-----+-------+---------------+ 
|  5  + 15.30 |     2         |
+-----+-------+---------------+
```

I want to query to show the time field side by side based on the "linked init id" matched the "id"

Eg: this is what the result should look like

```
+-----+-------+-------+
|  id | time1 | time2 |
+-----+-------+-------+   
|  1  | 10.00 | 15.00 |  //because id value "1" = linked init id value "1"
+-----+-------+-------+
|  2  | 11.00 | 15.00 |  //because id value "2" = linked init id value "2"
+-----+-------+-------+
```

How can I do this?

Note : each id can have only 0 or 1 linked id row

Comment: Possible mistake: isn't in the second table's last time (for row id 2, time2 column) supposed to be 15:30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table with itself:

```
SELECT time1.id, time1.time AS time1, time2.time as time2
FROM Table time1
JOIN Table time2 ON time2.[linked init id] = time1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below script-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba8d682bfb3e72547efb16d8e591943d)

```
SELECT A.linked_init_id, B.time Time1,A.Time Time2 
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.linked_init_id = B.id
WHERE A.linked_init_id <> 0
```